# display the missing icmp_seq count | ping command

Tags: linux, awk, grep, ping, gawk

I am looking for something which shows me the missing `ICMP` package when running ping command or which can display failed in the output. Example below

Current output where we are missing the icmp_seq count.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=52 ttl=64 time=0.831 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=53 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=54 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=55 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=56 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
```

Desired Output which will count the icmp_seq if missing then show error

```
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=51 ttl=64 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=52 ttl=64 time=0.831 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=53 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
Failed
Failed
Failed 
Failed
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=58 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=59 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
Failed
Failed
Failed
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So far I have managed to write the below command. I can run it in background & `tailf` the file which is getting created.

```
[root@connect ~]# touch result.txt; while true; do ping  -c 1 -w 2 192.168.56.11 || echo “`date` ping faild” >> result.txt; sleep 1; done
```

---

Editor's note: The poster probably wanted to write the following instead of `` “`date` ping faild” ``:

```sh
"$(date) ping failed"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ping `-O` for a mention of ***O***utstanding packets. A package is never sure lost, but if you use `-O`, an outstanding package will result in a line like

```
Thu 04 Mar 2021 05:32:04 PM CET no answer yet for icmp_seq=232
```

So you could do:

```
ping -O 192.168.56.11 | sed "s/.*no answer yet.*/failed/g"
```

to get your desired output.

Comment: As @Thorsten Staerk mentioned, the -O option alone will give you a very similar result to what you were looking for. The right part of his command was meant to replace the standard error message with your requested output, but I understand that it was just an example and that you don't really care about the exact error message as long as the output with the missing sequence is there. The standard ping output should meet your needs then.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

check this [code](https://gist.github.com/somic/712175)

this just parse the ping output

```
bash-4.1$ cat ping.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#
# analyzes ping output on Linux and looks for missed returns
# based on icmp_seq
#
# ping output is expected on stdin
#

BEGIN { num = 0 }
$5 ~ /icmp_seq=/ {
    split($5, res, /=/);
    if (res[2] != num + 1) {
        print "missed between", num, "and", res[2] }
    num = res[2];
}


bash-4.1$ cat ping_result.txt
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=52 ttl=64 time=0.831 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.11: icmp_seq=53 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms


bash-4.1$ awk -f ping.awk ping_result.txt
missed between 0 and 38
missed between 38 and 52
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to use this script .

Comment: check the modified answer

Comment: Seems that I need to run the `ping 192.168.56.11` and capture the log then I need to run the above script which will calculate the output am I right.

Comment: yes.. you are correct

Comment: I will be having atleast 14 screen which will be monitored & We need real time ping failed

Comment: what is your OS ?

Comment: Centos 7 is the OS

Comment: can you check this post... http://superuser.com/questions/270083/linux-ping-show-time-out

Comment: I tried the script but the thing is icmp_seq is not in sequence, and we did a test with that script sometime it skips to show ping down.

Comment: Does not work properly for pings by DNS name, works only by ip.

Answer (score 1):

On *Linux*, could use:

`fping -l google.com`

The above command will show **statistics**:

- Average elapsed time for each request.
- Percentage of package lost overall.

---

### Sample output

```
google.com : [160], 84 bytes, 32.0 ms (39.1 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [161], 84 bytes, 32.3 ms (39.1 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [162], 84 bytes, 33.8 ms (39.1 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [163], 84 bytes, 31.3 ms (39.0 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [164], 84 bytes, 32.8 ms (39.0 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [165], 84 bytes, 37.3 ms (39.0 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [166], 84 bytes, 32.4 ms (38.9 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [167], 84 bytes, 36.1 ms (38.9 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [168], 84 bytes, 32.8 ms (38.9 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [169], 84 bytes, 33.8 ms (38.8 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [170], 84 bytes, 32.6 ms (38.8 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [171], 84 bytes, 33.0 ms (38.8 avg, 0% loss)
google.com : [172], 84 bytes, 33.2 ms (38.7 avg, 0% loss)
^C
google.com : xmt/rcv/%loss = 173/173/0%, min/avg/max = 31.3/38.7/261
```

**Tips:**

- `ctrl + c` to stop it, and it will show an additional line of statistics, include:
  package sent / package received / lost percentage, min/avg/max of elapse time.

---

### Install

It's not installed by default, could install it via:

- Ubuntu / Mint
  `sudo apt install fping`

Answer (score 0):

The trick you could use is to create a loop to run the `ping` command with the option `-c` to send only 1 packet:

```
 while : ; do 
    ping -c1 -w1 192.168.56.11 | sed -n '/^64 bytes/p;/0 received/s/.*/Failed/p'
 done
```

The `-w` is specifying the timeout in second that will be triggered in case of host unreachable.

The `sed` command prints the ping output in case of success, and replace the ping output by `Failed` in case of failure.